# Quick way of duplicating object keys, but with different values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have an object like this:

```
object_1 = {
  a: 10,
  b: 5,
  c: 15
};
```

Is there a quick way to create another object that only has the same keys, like?

```
object_2 = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}
```

I know `Object.keys(object_1)` gives me an array with the keys but I don't know how to assign them as keys in the new object.

```
object_2 = Object.assign({}, Object.keys(object_1))
```

If I could somehow invert that array that would work :D

Comment: Are you trying to reset the values to `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the keys of the object with Array#reduce, and create a new object:

```js
var object_1 = {
  a: 10,
  b: 5,
  c: 15
};

var object_2 = Object.keys(object_1).reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = 0, o), {});

console.log(object_2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with mapped objects and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var object1 = { a: 10, b: 5, c: 15 },
    object2 = Object.assign(...Object.keys(object1).map(k => ({ [k]: 0 })));

console.log(object2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.reduce` as above or `forEach` to create a new object with the same keys and initialized values like below (This is without arrow function and other spread operator related to ES6)

```js
    var object_2 = {};
    object_1 = {
     a: 10,
     b: 5,
     c: 15
    };
    Object.keys(object_1).forEach( function(x){ object_2[x] = 0});
    console.log(object_2);
```